# Remote debug Firefox over the internet

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox-addon, remote-debugging, firefox-developer-tools

I just found the following great chrome extension [devtool sremote](https://github.com/auchenberg/devtools-remote).
Is there a similar add-on for firefox or explorer?

Or, better is there a javascript I can use for remote cross-browser debuging?

Comment: I agree this is super cool. I haven't looked around yet but it would be nice if Firefox has this as well.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox and especially the Mozilla Developer Edition has quite a good selection of tools  built in including for remote debugging.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools -> https://wiki.mozilla.org/Remote_Debugging_Protocol